# Geometry Nodes - How to assign vertex group in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

I added a plane.

[image]

Instanced objects on it.

[image]

Assigned vertex group on it.

[image]

(I'm stuck at this step) How do I make it look exactly like this by using Geometry Nodes?

Comment: Can you please specify what you mean with assigned vertex group. What are you trying to do with the vertex group and to what did you assign a vertex group

Comment: @Phönix64 Hi, my English is really bad and that may led to the misinterpretation of the question. Someone actually answered below, and their answer is what I was trying to interpret in the question. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @HuyHồVĩnh Hey your English is definitely not bad.

Comment: @Neil Aw that is very nice of you. In fact you didn't have to spend your precious time complementing me but you still did anyway. What a thoughtful person. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I’m interpreting your question correctly, and you just want to restrict the set of points where instances are created using a vertex group, you can use the *Point Separate* node:

[image]

In this example, my vertex group is named “no cubes”.

If you want the inverse, i.e. you want the cubes to only be instanced at the vertices contained in the vertex group, then you can use the Geometry 2 output of the Point Separate node, instead.

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer and this is actually what I was trying to interpret in the question. My English is bad and I'm sorry if my question confused you.

Comment: It seems that in v3.0, several of these nodes are no longer available.  How would I get the Vertex Group in 3.x?

Comment: @james_t, vgroup can be loaded as a float or boolean input. See answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/241925/blender-3-0-0-how-to-use-a-vertex-group-in-geometry-nodes

Comment: @SergeL -- the little games developers play to tweek to their perfection ... and confuse the rest of us following tutorials and exchange advice!

Comment: @SergeL -- I can now get the vgrp, but I still cannot figure out how to get to the solution above.  Should I re-post this question?  I guess the solution above was from 2.93?

Answer (score 1):

The node is now called *Separate Geometry* and allows you to to pick what mesh datatype to discriminate by any datatype. When you add the node, link the *Selection* to a *Group Input*, then you can click the plus cross icon thing to select your vertex group