# Blender 3.0.0 - How to use a vertex group in geometry nodes?

Tags: node-editor, vertices, geometry, groups

Does anyone know a way I can utilize vertex groups to limit the instancing in v. 3.0.0 ?

[Here is a thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/222257/geometry-nodes-how-to-assign-vertex-group-in-geometry-nodes) explaining nicely what I'm also trying to do. The thing is, 3.0.0 Beta apparently removed nodes (point instance, attribute nodes, etc.) that would let me type in the vertex group name. I went through virtually all geometry nodes available in 3.0.0. but I cannot see anything that I can plug my vertex group into. Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 17):

In Blender 3.0, attributes can no longer be accessed directly using the name of the attribute. Instead, attributes are stored in 'fields', which use diamond-shaped node sockets. You can connect a field to the 'Group Input' node, allowing you to select an attribute or vertex group in the modifier panel. This allows you to use the same node tree on different objects, even if they have different vertex group names.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Superb! I knew there was something I can do to make that input field show up, either in the modifier or the one of the nodes. I tried this, it worked like a charm. Many thanks @BlenderUser123!

Comment: hi, i tried the same but vertex group input only accept a number value, won't allow me to type in/select the vertex group name, or did i misunderstood sth here?

Comment: How unintuitive.  How did "Vertex Group" label appear on your Group Input Node?   Mine still says "Selection", even though I chose a Vertex Group by name in my GN properties.

Comment: @james_t, "Vertex Group" is renamed "Selection" - a default name for boolean type of data. Input name could be easily changed through the N-panel of Geometry Nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to fix it by clicking the *Input Attribute Toggle* button (the little 'cross' next to the input in the modifier panel). Should change it from a 0/1 input to a dropdown where you can select the vertex group.

Answer (score 0):

I just got all this to work. Once you have created the vertex group inputs you can isolate the vertex group geometry with the 'Separate Geometry' node. This is very useful for setting different materials to different vertex groups on an object.