# Blender 3.0: Vertex group as selection for "Separate Geometry"

Tags: node-editor

My question is actually being answered already here: [Blender 3.0.0 - How to use a vertex group in geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/241925/blender-3-0-0-how-to-use-a-vertex-group-in-geometry-nodes)

... however the solution does not work for me.

If I am connecting the selection field of a "Separate Geometry" node to the "Group Input" node, it generates a new entry field in the modifier view. However the values permitted/accepted there are 0 and 1. Nothing else. I cannot specify a vertex group name  there. None of the available input types (String, Boolean, Collection and many more) will also allow any such entry.

So: How can a specify a vertex group as an input/selection for a "Separate Geometry" node?

[image: screen shot]

Thanks in advance

Boris

Answer (score 1):

In the Modifier, you need to click on the icon after *Selection* and then left click on the field.  This will bring up a menu that will allow you to select the vertex group.  Here's an example from one of my setups.  The menu will show different values for you, of course:

[image: details of selection menu]

Comment: Hi Marty, thanks a lot! This is the solution. Very well hidden feature ;-)