# Geometry Nodes: Instance on Points - How to omit a vertex group

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a simple geo-node array that instances a mesh on the points of my mesh. Object -> Instance on Points -> Translate Instances -> Group Output.

How might I tell this array to omit any vertices found in a given vertex group?

Thanks in advance.

[This thread is supposed to address it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/241925/blender-3-0-0-how-to-use-a-vertex-group-in-geometry-nodes). But I can't actually divine a solution to my problem within it.

[image: My node array]

In this array, I just *know* that I need to put Delete Geometry some place and then plug my vertex group to effectively mask them out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. connect 'Selection' in your 'Instances on Points' node to an empty socket in your 'Group Input' node
2. check under the modifiers panel you now have a numeric field with a 'spreadsheet' icon, be sure to CLICK that ICON and then type your vertex group name
3. that should do it, maybe add a Boolean Math if you need to reverse selection

[image: instances on points]

[image: instances on faces]

Comment: GOT IT! Thanks so much. The key bit was to remember to CLICK on the Boolean symbol. If you just enter the string in (as I have repeatedly been doing), it basically thinks you are putting text in a number field. But if you click the button, that must change the field state or something.

Comment: yes that happened to me too, it's not so obvious and also not something you see in other places... will edit answer