# Geometry Nodes -- exclude vertex group

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, vertex-groups, surface-deform

I'm using geometry nodes to deform meshes using Noise on all 3 axes, like this
[image]

<sup>Click images to see full res</sup>

But there is one mesh where I'd like to discard the z-axis noise for a certain vertex group. That is, I'd still like that vertex group to be deformed on the x and y axes, just not on the z axis.

Following [this discussion from another thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254272/geometry-nodes-instance-on-points-how-to-omit-a-vertex-group), I was able to use a 'boolean NOT' to exclude a vertex group, but it discards changes on all the axes, not just z.

[image]

Also tried separating them and using a mesh boolean but I was not sure of the wiring. I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Your selection mask should modify only the Z coordinate. To do that, you need a Switch node connected to the Input Boolean (this must be unconnected from the Set Position node) and to the Z socket of the Combine XYZ node. True/False sockets of the Switch node should be connected to 0 for nodes not to change and to the Noise Texture node for the others.

Comment: @StefLAncien that worked beautifully! I used a float switch. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'Switch node'.
Here you can see checking in 'Switch node' is vertex in vertex group, then return 1, else return 0.
Multiplying (1,1,0) (for vertex group) on noise texture vector I get noise vector with 0 on Z axis.
[image]