# Geometry Nodes in v3.x - How to instance onto vertex group?

Tags: geometry-nodes

This is not a duplicate of [Geometry Nodes - How to assign vertex group in geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/222259/111042), because it appears that the answer is obsolete in v3.x.  How sad!

I want to Instance an object (here a "Sphere") onto vertices of another object (here a "Cube") similar to Vertices Instancing onto a parent object:

[image]

Now I want to use the vertices I specified into the "Group1" Vertex Group on Cube:

[image]

I finally figure out (not through the Documentation that never describes how to get properties to Group Input!!), how to get the Vertex Group:

[image]

But I'm not sure what to do from here, as several Geometry Nodes from the previous Q/Solution are no longer available, which probably makes much of the Stack Exchange and tutorial information on Geo Nodes obsolete and confusing.

[image]

Here is my progress: [image]

v3.0.0 solutions welcome.   Hurry up before they release 3.1!

Comment: The answer @Chris gave is correct. Just a short explanation: the difference between "Instance on Points" and "Instances to Points" is, that the first one creates instances on points of a point cloud plugged into the _Points_ input (what you want to do). The second creates points at the origins from a set of instances plugged into the _Instances_ input.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann -- thanks, although the term "point cloud" confuses me.  i think of point clouds as something from physics, and vertices as something from meshes!  I guess a vertex is also a point in terms of GNs.

Comment: I understand your confusion :) But there's a misunderstanding, in _Geometry Nodes_ vertices of meshes are called vertices as well. Points (summarized under _Point Cloud_ in the _Spreadsheet_) are virtual points that you get e.g. when you use the _Distribute Points on Faces_ node. It is just that Blender inherently takes vertices for points if you plug a mesh into the _Intance on Points_. Just like in the _Shader Editor_ where Blender converts _RGB Color_ into a factor between 0 to 1 when plugging into a _Color Ramp_ for example... Think of it as an automatic format conversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just use the instance on points node:

[image]

[image]

Note: this is just a very basic setup. It would be cleaner if you ask e.g. with a greater than node after vertex group input, if the value is bigger than 0.5 (just an example, tweak to your needs)